# How to I tune MongoDB Memory management under docker?

Tags: windows, mongodb, docker, memory-management

I have a Docker container running MongoDB which is running really slowly.  The Db is about 5-6m documents, single collection, total size (from Compass) of about 75Gb.  Its running on a Windows Server with 96Gb allocated, and Docker has 32Gb allocated, but the container is showing memory usage of only 60Mb.  Resource Monitor has a mongod process with a working set of 42Gb but I'm not convinced this is right.

Any advice on how to set config to maximise available memory for Mongo / Docker?  I've looked at other threads but nothing really addresses Mongo / Docker / Windows combo as far as I can see.

Thanks,

Comment: I'm also wondering this. What have you tried?

Comment: I've managed to make substantial improvements in performance through index tuning (they were not good before!).  Something in the region of 10x query speed.  The Memory problem I am experiencing was more to do with Docker (and my lack of understanding of how to work it) than Mongo, so I've moved it to native and its working a lot better now.

Comment: yeah I'm finding docker is good in development/samll scale but terrible in production.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was two fold:
a) performance was due to poor indexing rather than anything else.  With tuning this has now been resolved
b) Memory management I found was confused by Docker, and Docker Desktop did not really help with diagnosis, so I've moved Mongo to native Windows and its now working a lot better.